# How can I extend partition into free space that is not directly before or after the partition? 

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, gparted

[image]

I want to add free space (323.69GB) to my Ubuntu file system (242.62GB). But as you can see I can't do this via GParted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can combine partitions, by using GParted.  You can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center, or click the image below.

Remember that gparted ***won't*** work on a mounted partition. First you have to ***unmount*** .

**NOTE: You might want to consider doing this from a live/bootable CD or USB, to be safe.  Also keep in mind that anytime you deal with partitions, there is risk involved in doing so.**

**NOTE: When dealing with partitions, always make sure that a backup is available in case something goes wrong.  You may consider [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Mitch has said you will need to do this from a live environment so that sda1 is not mounted. Also make sure that swap is not being used - if necessary right click on the swap partition and swapoff.

You'll then need to move the partition with the install (sda1) to the left so that the unallocated space is to it's right.

Then you can expand sda1 to use the unallocated space.

*It could take a long time - do not use battery - do not assume it has hung and turn it off. Ensure you have backups of data you can't afford to lose.*

It would be easier in my mind to just create a new partition in the unallocated space and add it to fstab so it is mounted on boot.