# Move entire installation to blank partition

Tags: 12.10, partitioning

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on a second hard drive (sdb).   I had a windows ntfs partition before that for storage but have subsequently purchased an external hard drive and transferred those files to it.  I then deleted the ntfs partition leaving blank space before Ubuntu.

Question - is there a fast way to move 12.10 over without hosing my system?  I really would prefer not to use Gparted as it is painfully slow.  I want to do this so when 13.04 comes out, I can install it next to 12.10.  I have never tried this so if you could be specific as possible with any advice.  Thanks everyone.

By the way, I did see this post:    [How can I extend partition into free space that is not directly before or after the partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170330/how-can-i-extend-partition-into-free-space-that-is-not-directly-before-or-after)

Comment: If you can give the exact locations of where your current Ubuntu partition is (e.g. sdb1) and where that free space is (another partition in another drive, e.g. sda1? just an unallocated space in sdb - immediately before/after ubuntu, etc.)...

Comment: According to the disk utility the drive is dev/sdc, but it really is dev/sdb.

Comment: And where is the free space?

Comment: Free space 1.2 TB, Extended Partition 1 - 309 GB, Free Space - 105 GB, Swap - Partition 5 (2.0 GB Swap) Filesystem - Partition 6 - 202 GB Ext4.  Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you would like is to **clone** your Ubuntu partition from a partition on one hard drive to a partition on another hard drive, and then delete (or format) the former.

For this you can follow the steps below:

1. Create a new partition in the free space of the other hard drive (this new partition should exactly equal to or larger that your Ubuntu partition).
2. Create a live [Clonezilla](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla) or [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) CD or USB and boot your computer with it.
3. Start Clonezilla and save your Ubuntu partition.
4. Make necessary changes to restore your saved Ubuntu partition as par [this FAQ](http://drbl.sourceforge.net/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/102_restore_image_to_different_partition.faq#102_restore_image_to_different_partition.faq).
5. Reboot your computer with live Clonezilla or Parted Magic, start Clonezilla and restore your Ubuntu partition to the new partition.
6. You can delete your former Ubuntu partition after making sure that the new Ubuntu partition is up and running.

Comment: No actually I want it on the same hard drive (secondary).  I want the main hard drive for W7 and data.

Comment: Without necessary details about your drives/partitions, it's very hard to try and give an answer. Anyway, if the post you mention does not offer the solution you require, I still think my answer offers a good solution, even if the source and target partitions are on the same hard drive/disk. This is all I can do for you I'm afraid with the available info.

Comment: I want 12.10 on the second hard drive, not the first (sda).  See sdb above.  I gather there is no way to just slide the entire installation over to the left without doing what you suggest.  I'm not clear what information you are asking for, but your solution is at best a roll of the dice. If I am wrong please correct me.  Further, if 13.04 can go before 12.10, then there is no reason to bother.  However, Grub would need to be updated in 12.10 to pick up 13.04.  I found that out when I installed Mint 14 in the same empty space sdb.  Why is Ubuntu calling my 2nd drive sdc - that is the question.

Comment: It's possible to move/slide a partition to the left or right as long as there is no non-empty partition in between and as long as this doesn't require moving it out of an extended partition. Otherwise **cloning** is required. Clonezilla is very reliable in such cases as long as you follow the instructions carefully (including the steps required in changing partition numbers). As for sdc, it's hard to tell for me I'm afraid.

Comment: Should I even bother?  When 13.04 is final, can I install it before 12.10 with no issues in the empty space and just update grub in 12.10?  That is what I am thinking of...

Comment: Perhaps this is the best solution. You can choose to install 13.04 anywhere you like but then you'll have grub under 13.04 taking over the boot management, which should also include 12.10 on the menu.

Comment: I hope you know I'm really am not trying to give you a hard time.  When I installed Mint 14 in the empty portion of the second hard drive, Grub did not pick up Mint 14.  I had to boot into 12.10 and update Grub, reboot, then both Ubuntu and Mint were recognized in Grub.

Comment: I also see such strange things happen sometimes. Normally, when you install a new linux distribution, its bootloader should successfully take over the boot management and generate a new grub menu with all other systems on the computer. In case of failure, **Boot-Repair** utility also comes very handy.